# How can I add a new event on Reminders using Python/PyObjC?

Tags: pyobjc

I'm new at pyObjC, and I'm trying to understand how I can add a new event on Reminder's App via script. I know that I will have to use EKEventStore, but I have a hard time understanding how to translate the objective-c to python correctly. Any thoughts?